# OAuth 2.0 where to securely store access token for long term use

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I am working with API that uses OAuth 2.0. Its' flow is like this:

1. In your application, you have a button which redirects you to the authorization server (APIs' in my case).
2. You either have to log in to APIs' website and give access to your application (press "allow" or "deny" button) or if you are already logged in, just give access to your application (press "allow" or "deny").
3. You get redirected back to your application with your new access token for making API calls.

Everything works for me, all is good but what I do not understand is how to deal with given access token so that the user, which has already authorized access to your application, would not have to give access again. Etc when he comes back to the application after a few days. It gives bad user experience (no one wants to grant access again and again).

Note: I am working with [Quizlet API](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow)

Answer (score 10):

First of all, Access tokens should be short lived. Consider it equal to short lived one time credential. If you are not convinced, check Azure AD token life time definitions linked here ["Configurable token lifetime properties"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties).

Its recommended to use define short lived access tokens, for example which expires after 1 hour. That way you avoid the complexity of storing them. You simply keep them in memory and use them to access protected resources.

> what I do not understand is how to deal with given access token so that the user, which has already authorized access to your application, would not have to give access again. Etc when he comes back to the application after a **few days**.

Well, here you should be talking about **[Refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)**. According to OAuth 2.0 specification, its refresh tokens which have longer life time. If you check with my earlier reference to Azure, you see that they can live up to 90 days. For Google, refresh tokens expire after 6 months (if they are not used). One can still revoke them.

Now when you are using refresh tokens, you are not using them to access protected resources. Refresh token should be exchanged to get access tokens. So if someone steal them, they still need client authentication (ex:- client id, redirect uri & client secret) to obtain access tokens. Still, protecting them is a must.

Regardless, [RFC6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) define some possibilities you can take on in section [5.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.3.3) to store secrets (tokens are secrets). You may use a client storage mechanism or utilise server backed to store tokens.

If your application has an back-end, one possibility is to correlate cookies to tokens. Cookie value could be a hash of the token which you have stored in back-end(probably in a database). When the back-end receive a request with a valid cookie value, it can retrieve the token stored against it. This is quite similar to "remember me" functionality.

**What if you can't control token life time (They are by default long lived) ?**

If you can obtain tokens hassle free, and if you can compromise end user experience, go for in memory storage where you will always retrieve new tokens for fresh access.

If you have a back-end for you application which can maintain the state between clients, push and store tokens at the back-end. Correlate client session with tokens, probably through cookies/sessions. Call secure APIs through back-end, without exposing stored tokens to client application.

Comment: I see. Right now, I do not receive refresh tokens, only the bearer one, which expires in "315360000". Can the default url parameter "prompt_approval=force" / "prompt=consent" be the reason why I do not receive it and the constant asking for access? Note: I am working with [Quizlet API](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization-code-flow) ([PHP example](https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/oauth-example-php))

Comment: Well, 315360000 value doesn't really make sense. Can you configure token expiration time ? I went through the documentation you pointed out and yes it doesn't mention about a refresh token. But again, can you configure authorisation server ?

Comment: I've read through the whole Quizlet documentation a few times and nowhere can be found anything about configuring anything with OAuth. In fact, they state that the token they give, lasts 10 years: "Quizlet access tokens last for 10 years, effectively providing 3rd-party applications access forever (without the user having to re-authorize)"

Comment: @Tomeister Okay, I came across this - https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/oauth2 . Well though they have support for Oauth 2.0 but seems they have adopted at draft stage, without considering impact of prolonged token lifetime. And yes, that number comes to 10 years, which is too much for today's standards.

Comment: @Tomeister In this scenario, you must always use SSL between APIs and your clients. You must store tokens in server end of your client, probably encrypted/hashed depending on your capacity. Then you need a mechanism to correlate token to client which obtained them. Probably cook could save you. HTTPS cookies specifically. Also, your front end client might not necessary require token at that end. Probably you could proxy through your back-end :) That way you never expose token to end users/front end of you app

Comment: But wouldn't user would have to give access to the application for every device he uses? Let's say user uses tablet, smartphone, and PC with two different browsers so he would have to give access four times instead of one, which OAuth aims to do, right? Or, in my situation, there is no way to give the best possible user experience?

Comment: Well, that make things complicated. Depending on your authorization server, you could get browser based SSO behaviour if you use same browser (First time user login, authorization server will set cookies to identify end user skipping login page for consequent authorization requests). But beyond that it's difficult to say. To my understanding its beyond OAuth spec.

Comment: "you could get browser based SSO behaviour if you use same browser" Can you give some explanation about this part? SSO stands for single sign-on? I am starting to get the feeling that I will have to stick with multiple authorizations and cookies (one per browser / device)

Comment: @Tomeister if authorization server use sessions to detect end user logged in state, after the first time you log in for authorization call, you may skip login when using same browser for other calls (till session is alive). Hope this helped

Comment: Yeah, I get that part. My problem is that, when sessions expire, user has to authorize again (press "allow") even when I have access token for that user

Comment: @Tomeister If you have unexpired, valid tokens, you shouldn't go to authoirzation server (No prompt).You should use same token to access protected endpoint. But if you cannot correlate token to user or tokens are invalid, then new tokens should be obtained

Comment: I am trying to do that (no prompt while having valid access token) but don't know how. That's why the only solution I could think of was to create cookies for different browsers user would use. But that way user still has to authorize the application for more than one time.

Comment: @Tomeister Well, cookie based approach is okay. But as you have figured out. Once a cookie is made, you must correlate the cookie to token. So the when a user comes back, based on the cookie, you must pass the token to client application. So that you can use valid token till it get invalidated

Comment: Oh, that is not a problem for me but I would rather go without cookies. It should be possible, right? How about "prompt_approval=none" / "prompt=none"? Sorry that this got way out of hand but I need to figure it out for good.

Comment: @Tomeister prompt parameter is not part of OAuth 2.0. It comes with OpenID Connect. that's why I haven't mention that in my comments. Prompt  can be associate with authorization server session, which is bound to browser.

Comment: So all in all, what are my choices for having user to authorize only one time per all devices? Only cookies?

Comment: Hi @KavinduDodanduwa I have  a similar issue. I have to generate an access token by automatically logging to the API provider's site (for this I am using Pupeteer) and using the request_token from that to generate an access token by calling their API to generate the access token. However, there seems to be rate limiting to their API, which is fairly high but I am concerned about a high load situation ( if I need to log in, generate a request token and use that to get access token to call the APIs., that will  be a minimum of three API calls for the user. Are there any best practices for this?

Comment: I was thinking of adding Redis to avoid any potential throttling, since that will handle  the expiry  of the token as well.